# What to do when theme and WordPress coding standards conflict?

Tags: theme-roots, coding-standards

I am considering different starter themes such as [_s](http://underscores.me/) and [roots](http://Roots.io/). Roots looks very good, especially its sass fork. Anyway, there's one thing that concerns me. It seems like Roots doesn't follow the WordPress coding standards of themes and plugins. What standard do I then follow if I want to use Roots as a starter theme?

Comment: Roots adheres to its own conventions with a bit less spacing and 2 space indentation compared to WP's 1 tab indentation. Well, I suppose it's better to stick to Roots' conventions as I'll be working in that codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very subjective question — though a very good and interesting one, and I'll try to provide my personal view on this.

In general, you should always try to adhere to the WordPress Coding Standards. The only exception to this is when you're changing existing code. Basically, when you're editing an existing "product" (e.g. a plugin or theme), you should use the coding standards the product follows. So, in your case you should adhere to the coding standards of the theme.

Even though this differentiation might seem quite black-and-white, it isn't. There's a lot of grey areas to consider. I'll try to cover a few of those, but let me first try to give a set of basic rules:

1. If you're not changing a product but building a new one or extending an existing one, use the **WordPress coding standards**.
2. If you're changing code in WordPress core, use the **WordPress coding standards** (even though the additional code might not adhere to them).
3. If you're changing a product and the code is readable and consistent in formatting, use the **original product's coding standards**.

In general, the most important thing of coding standards is to keep your code readable. So, when deciding whether you're going to use the original coding standards or the WordPress coding standards, ask yourself the question: **what makes the code in this product as a whole more readable**, using the original or WordPress coding standards?

## Coding standards for child themes

This isn't actually a grey area, but it's an interesting point to clarify: when extending a product (so not changing but really extending), you're providing an additional product dependent on an existing product. This is a separate product, and you should adhere to the WordPress coding standards.

## Ridiculous coding standards

If you're changing a product and it has ridiculous coding standards (e.g. coding standards that severely damage code readability), you should opt for using the WordPress coding standards.

## Inconsistent coding standards

If the original product doesn't seem to be incosistent in adhering to a particular set of coding standards, you should use the WordPress coding standards for your own, new code.

Answer (score 4):

> Roots adheres to its own conventions with a bit less spacing and 2 space indentation compared to WP's 1 tab indentation

Here is what the codex say about [indentations](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#indentation)

> Your indentation should always reflect logical structure. Use real tabs and not spaces, as this allows the most flexibility across clients.
>
> Exception: if you have a block of code that would be more readable if things are aligned, use spaces:

This is not a matter of sticking to coding standards or not. Always remember, readability in code is very very important, and the coding standards makes provision for this.

On your question,  the Roots theme are still doing things within the coding standards. I would also think that such a successful theme would not risk their reputation to cross the line. Stick with what Roots offer you, they are within coding standards, so you should keep to their structure for readability

References:

- [Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/)
- [PHP coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/)
- [HTML Coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/html/)
- [Javascript Coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/javascript/)
- [CSS Coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/css/)

**EDIT**

This question has recieved close votes as "primarily opion based" which might be correctly so, but is sicking to coding standards really primarily opion based?

As I've pointed out by using the references, the codex clearly states the coding standards you should be using, what the exceptions are to the rule, how the standards should be applied in practice and examples on how to implement these standards.

I really think that this whole exercise comes down to reading and **understanding** what is said it those pages in the codex.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying your answer to my question would be. Should I use 2 spaces or tabs in order to be consistent with the theme? (yes/no)

Comment: To be consisted with the theme, use the two spaces. Remember the exception rule here which I stated for readability.  The codex do cover for that

Comment: Now I get what you're saying. I haven't thought of it that way before. So I guess you could say that I still follow the standards!

Comment: You are correct. The roots theme are coded to standard, and I really do think that such a successfull theme would not risk its reputation to break the rules when it comes to coding standards

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it make much more sense

Comment: I actually did so elaborate on my downvote in my answer. This *is* subjective, as it's regarding existing code being adjusted. Your answer has too little to do with the question: it's about general coding standards. The question, on the other hand, is about what to do when the coding standards and the code you're modifying are different: an interesting question that shouldn't be answer in such a black-and-white fashion. However, your answer is now more comprehensive — I've removed my downvote. Still, I do believe you're viewing this too simplistically.

Comment: All good now you two? :) Ok, I'm not a moderator, but I did cast that very first close vote as *primarily opinion based* for a reason. That happened shortly after the question has been asked. I agree that this is a interesting question, but stand by my casting the close vote. The former is the reason why, after I realized that there are going to be two helpful answers, I casted every single up-vote that happened until now. Sure some might argue that, but I'm all for positive reinforcement. Besides the question and *both* answers together are useful. @engelen

Comment: The discussion that happened actually proofs that this is *primarily opinion based*, because as outside observer your answers are similar to partly identical and in any case complementary. The latter makes them actually more valuable if seen combined, which is actually more important from a community standpoint. Btw I don't want to get involved in the "fight", just wanted to say what's on my mind. It might just be helpful too. @engelen

Comment: @ialocin thanks for your insight. I also casted a close vote :-) btw. I actually posted my answer as complement to engelen's answer, but yes, I do agree. At the end of the day, it is our duty to keep our answers, and most of all this site, constructive. That is why, if you downvote an answer, leave a comment and state why. We all want to improve in our wrongs. Questions are something else, downvote bad questions, lol